# Android - Setting the background of TextView programmatically according to Dark and Light Mode Themes

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

I have an app with themes (Dark and Light Mode Theme). And want to set background of TextView programmatically.

But the problem is,
when I change the color, and change the app theme to Dark Mode then the color has not been changed. It should changed according to Theme Settings.

`txtTitle.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))`

Not working, just black background shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `backgroundColor` does not change because you always set it to `R.color.black` despite the current theme. To be theme-sensitive you must create a color resource which is defined for light and dark mode.

Inside your `res` folder you must create a `values` folder for night mode `values-night`.

In both you define a color resource which is set to the TextView.

*Light mode*

```
<resources>
   <color name="text_background">@android:color/black</color>
</resources>
```

*Dark mode*

```
<resources>
   <color name="text_background">@android:color/white</color>
</resources>
```

*In code*

```
txtTitle.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.text_background))
```